# How to do increase UItableview height inside UItableviewcell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I Just create `UITableview`(Second `UITableview`) inside `UItableviewcell`. I need to increase `UItableviewcell` height based on second UITableview number of cell(second `UITableview's` cells had a different height).

**1st tableview:**

```
extension ViewController:UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
   // no of row #1
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OrderTimelineCell", for: indexPath) as! OrderTimelineCell
      return cell;
   }
}
```

**1st tableview Cell:**

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
   tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
   tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: tableView.contentSize.height).isActive = true //always return 44*#cells
}
extension OrderTimelineCell:UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TimelineTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TimelineTableViewCell
      cell.label.text = array[indexpath.row] // text height different
      return cell
   }
}
```

I expect output to display all cells of Second `UITableview` inside 1st `UITableview` cells.

but the actual output is cell height == #no of cell * 44

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify height in this method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == indexOfExtendedCell {
         return 100 // or another height
    }
    return 44
}
```

Comment: don't want to specify statically (return 100). because, dynamically text comes inside Cell

Comment: You have to specify it via this method. Every changing of subviews of cell needed to calculate of height and update height here. It is not awful.